# Failing to check and change img path

Tags: javascript

I have two images (one black thumbs up image and a green one) and the idea is the following:

- when the page loads it starts with the black thumbs up;
- if i click the image it changes to the green thumbs up;
- if i click it again it goes back to the black one;

This is the code i have. What am i doing wrong?

```
<script>
    function changeImage(){
        If (document.getElementById('like').src='like.png') {
            document.getElementById('like').src='like2.png';
        }
    }
</script>

<img class='feed2' src='Imagens/like.png' id="like" onclick="changeImage()">
```

Comment: `If` should be lower case, and your conditional needs to use a double equals.

Comment: Also your path is "Imagens/like.png", not "like.png"

Comment: [voting to close this as off-topic (#2)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Solution using `Jquery` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340983/switching-an-image-using-jquery

Comment: I'd be tempted to do this with a custom checkbox too, here is a useful site to generate one for you http://www.csscheckbox.com/css-checkbox-generator.php

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:  `If` is not the same as `if`.  Your [JS console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) should have complained about that.

Problem 2: After correcting that,

```
if (document.getElementById('like').src = 'like.png') {
```

will:

1. Assign `like.png` as the `src` (you meant to say `==`)
2. Which will always be true
3. So the following line will also run, assigning `like2.png` as the image, every time.

When all is said and done, you want:

```
function changeImage(){
    if (document.getElementById('like').src == 'Imagens/like.png') {
        document.getElementById('like').src = 'Imagens/like2.png';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('like').src = 'Imagens/like.png';
    }
}
```

Comment: the if isn't working. i tried put an alert('test') and it didn't show.

Comment: i'm using sublime text , what other console would you recommend?

Comment: Sublime Text is an editor. The [Javascript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) is part of your browser.

Comment: ups sorry , i figure out now that it's not what you meant. I'm portuguese and my english is a bit bad...